Exporting a Longformer model to ONNX using optimum.exporters
I have trained and finetuned a longformer model with my data.
Now I am trying to export that into ONNX format, using optimum exporter.
Since it's not supported off the bat (from what I can figure), I created my own config file. I'm not completely sure I'm doing this correctly
class LongformerOnnxConfig(OnnxConfig):
    DEFAULT_ONNX_OPSET = 11
    MIN_TRANSFORMERS_VERSION = "4.39.3"
    is_transformers_support_available = False

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__(config)
        # Define custom properties from your model's config if necessary

    @property
    def inputs(self):
        return {
            "input_ids": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
            "attention_mask": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},
            "global_attention_mask": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"}
        }

    @property
    def outputs(self):
        return {
            "logits": {0: "batch_size", 1: "num_labels"}
        }

    def generate_dummy_inputs(self, tokenizer, batch_size=1, seq_length=128):
        # Generate dummy inputs for testing or exporting
        dummy_input = "This is a dummy input."
        inputs = tokenizer(dummy_input, return_tensors="pt", max_length=seq_length, padding="max_length")
        return {
            "input_ids": inputs["input_ids"],
            "attention_mask": inputs["attention_mask"],
            # Add global_attention_mask if needed
            "global_attention_mask": torch.zeros_like(inputs["attention_mask"])
        }

    @property
    def default_onnx_opset(self):
        return 11  # Depending on the required opset for your ONNX export, default is 11

    @property
    def torch_to_onnx_dtype(self):
        return {
            torch.float32: "float",
            torch.float16: "float16"
        }


Then I try to run the conversion with the following code:

model = LongformerForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("<<Finetuned model from HuggingFace>>", use_safetensors=True)
onnx_config = LongformerOnnxConfig(model.config)
with torch.no_grad():
        model.config.return_dict = True
        model.eval()
        onnx_model_path,
        output = onnx_model_path
        export(
                model=model,
                config=onnx_config,
                output=output,
        )

But I get the following error:
raise MinimumVersionError(optimum.exporters.error_utils.MinimumVersionError: The current version of Transformers does not allow for the export of the model. Minimum required is 4.39.3, got: 4.39.3
No matter what version I give it, I get the same error.
What am I doing wrong?

Which version of optimum do you use?

I'm using 1.18.1

Did you try installing onnxruntime-gpu==1.14.1 ?

Maybe related: https://github.com/huggingface/optimum/issues/1774
